# Does a nested anonymous function in Javascript associated with an event handler not work?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

If I use a **named function** instead,it does do well :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){
       var img = document.getElementById('im');
        img.onload = fun();

   } 
function fun()
{
  alert("Image loaded");
}          
</script>

<img src="picture.png" id="im"/>
```

But, my question is that when I try to do the same by using **an anonymous function**(*as shown below*),why does it not work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
       window.onload = function(){
       var img = document.getElementById('im');
          img.onload = function(){

          alert("Image loaded");
        }
       }            
</script>

<img src="picture.png" id="im"/>
```

Comment: make it `img.onload = fun;`

Comment: `img.onload = fun();` , you have to assign a handler not invoke it yourself

Comment: If I make it as img.onload = fun; then it does not work in my browser @gurvinder372

Comment: @rosemary The second example you post is correct, there may be something wrong with the loading of the image.

Comment: But the image is loaded well here @A1rPun

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the image is already loaded before you attach a handler to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example `fun` is called when the event handler is attached to the image (after the image has loaded).

In your second example, the anonymous function is attached to the image after the image has loaded.

To see the behaviour you want, try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('im');
    img.onload = fun;

    img.src = "picture.png";
  } 

  function fun()
  { 
    alert("Image loaded");
  }          
</script>

<img id="im"/>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
   window.onload = function() {
     var img = document.getElementById('im');
     img.onload = function(){
       alert("Image loaded");
     }

     img.src="picture.png" 
   }            
</script>

<img id="im"/>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fun()
  { 
    alert("Image loaded");
  }          
</script>

<img id="im" src="picture.png" onload="javascript:fun();"/>
```

Comment: no, I wouldn't recommend the last example either. I was trying to make the point that the event handler has to be bound before the image loads.